# Algorithm to output all instances of stable matching

Tags: algorithms

So the Gale-Shapley algorithm is just one way to output one stable matching instance. Is there any algorithm that can allow us to output all stable matching solutions ? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried backtracking? For most algorithms that finds one solution to a problem, it can be modified to find all solutions, rather easily, for example, by adding backtracking.

Comment: There can be exponentially many solutions, so any such algorithm could potentially take a very long time, depending on the input instance.  (But it might be possible to find all solutions in time polynomial in the number of solutions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dan Gusfield gave such an algorithm in his paper [Three Fast Algorithms for Four Problems in Stable Marriage](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0216010). The algorithm uses $O(n^2)$ space, and takes time $O(n^2 + nS)$, where $S$ is the number of stable matchings.